# TJClipboardManager in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to copy selected text, using this:

```
uses
  Androidapi.Helpers, Androidapi.jni , AndroidAPI.JNIBridge, 
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,  FMX.Helpers.Android,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;

procedure TForm2.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myclipboard : JClipboardManager;
  s: string;
begin
  myclipboard := TJClipboardManager.create;
  myclipboard.getText;
  showmessage(BoolToStr(myclipboard.hasText));
end;`
```

There are a lot of samples in Java, but i'm not enough strong yet to understand it[image]

Comment: Have you tried declaring myclipboard as `TJClipboardManager` instead of `JClipboardManager`?

Comment: Yeah, the result: [DCC Error] Unit2.pas(86): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TJClipboardManager' and 'JClipboardManager'

Comment: Use the platform service [`IFMXClipboardService`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXClipboardService)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to instantiate the `ClipboardManager` class directly, but instead use the `Content.getSystemService()` method to obtain the correct manager object.  The Android documentation even says so:

> You do not instantiate this class directly; instead, retrieve it through getSystemService(Class).

So, you have to do this instead:

```
function GetClipboardManager: JClipboardManager;
var
  obj: JObject;
begin
  obj := SharedActivityContext.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
  if Assigned(obj) then
    Result := TJClipboardManager.Wrap((obj as ILocalObject).GetObjectID)
  else
    Result := nil;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myclipboard : JClipboardManager;
begin
  myclipboard := GetClipboardManager;
  if Assigned(myclipboard) then
  begin
    //...
  end;
end;
```

Do note that depending on which version of Android you are running on, `Context.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)` will return either a [`android.content.ClipboardManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html) (HoneyComb+) or [`android.text.ClipboardManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html) object.  Not sure how well Delphi handles that, if at all.  You will have to look at the declaration of `JClipboardManager` to see which one it is accessing.  The latter one was deprecated in Android API level 11.

Embarcadero wants you to use FMX's cross-platform [`IFMXClipboardService`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXClipboardService) interface instead:

```
uses
  FMX.Platform, System.Rtti;

procedure TForm2.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Clipboard: IFMXClipboardService;
  value: TValue;
  hasText: boolean;
  s: string;
begin
  hasText := False;
  if PlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXClipboardService, IInterface(Clipboard)) then
  begin
    value := Clipboard.GetClipboard;
    hasText := value.TryAsType<String>(s);
  end;
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(hasText));
  if hasText then ShowMessage(s);
end;
```

Comment: You must not use uninitialized local variable `s` ;o)

Comment: `string` variables are auto-initialized by the compiler.

Comment: It's a bad habit though, and a bad example to set.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Why is it a bad habit to let the compiler auto-initialize variables declared as compiler-managed data types?  Most Delphi developers know that `string` is amongst the compiler-managed data types.  Are you really one of those people that explicitly writes `s := '';` everywhere you declare a `string` variable?

Comment: It gets more interesting with function return values. They look like they'll also be initialized. But that depends on what happens at the call site. I know this isn't a return value, but if you take your path then you end up with a rule that has multiple exceptional clauses.  I'd rather be explicit and a bit more verbose in this scenario. That doesn't mean that you always write `s := '';` whenever you declare a string. Just that you always assign it at some point.